# Can not get routing of two points on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, routes, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to make an android app as like as uber app where user can input origin location and destination location.Then it will show the routing.

I made an app which can route from current place to destination place.Destination place is taken by dragging the marker.Here,Marker is passing latlng of position in onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) method.

Also there are two edittext boxes which will take location using Placepicker.When I am inserting place,markers are appearing on map.One for origin and another for destination place.But routing is not happening.Because I can not pass latlng of those markers in onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) method.
I need to pass latitude and longitude of markers in onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) method.But the problem is I can only pass latitude and longitude of one marker.How can I pass latlng of two markers in onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)?
Or any other way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ORIGIN_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity());

            etOrigin.setText(place.getAddress());
            Originlnlt.setText(place.getLatLng().toString());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(getlong(place.getLatLng().toString()),getlat(place.getLatLng().toString())), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(new LatLng(getlong(place.getLatLng().toString()),getlat(place.getLatLng().toString()))).title("Origin Position").snippet("I have found me"));
            String toastMsg = String.format("Origin Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



    if (requestCode == DESTINATION_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity());
            etDestination.setText(place.getAddress());
            Destinationlnlt.setText(place.getLatLng().toString());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(getlong(place.getLatLng().toString()),getlat(place.getLatLng().toString())), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions
                    .position(new LatLng(getlong(place.getLatLng().toString()),
                            getlat(place.getLatLng().toString())))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)).title(place.getName().toString()).snippet(place.getAddress().toString()).title("Destination Position").snippet("I want to go"));
            String toastMsg = String.format("Destination Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
    //TODO
}
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    btnFindPath = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
    etOrigin = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
    etDestination = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etDestination);
    Originlnlt = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.originL);
    Destinationlnlt = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.desL);
    btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //sendRequest();
            Object dataTransfer[] = new Object[2];
            dataTransfer = new Object[3];
            String url = getDirectionsUrl();
            GetDirectionsData getDirectionsData = new GetDirectionsData();
            dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
            dataTransfer[1] = url;
            dataTransfer[2] = new LatLng(end_latitude, end_longitude);
            //dataTransfer[2] = new LatLng( 22.34730250000000,91.83745703125001);
            getDirectionsData.execute(dataTransfer);
        }
    });
    etOrigin.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // Always use a TextKeyListener when clearing a TextView to prevent android
                // warnings in the log

                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), ORIGIN_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    etDestination.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // Always use a TextKeyListener when clearing a TextView to prevent android
                // warnings in the log

                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), DESTINATION_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: you can do this using *PolylineOptions* ..

Comment: Yes.I used PolylineOptions on GetDirectionData class.